# Sentinal-2 Georeferenceing

Tags: georeferencing, image

Are Sentinel-2 data geometrically corrected or do they need to be georeferenced as an image to image?

What is the best software for processing?

Comment: With semi-automatic classification plugin in QGIS you can go all the process from downloading, to correcting, converting to TOA radiance and using them for classification

Answer (score 5):

That depends what processing level you are referring to. Most data is delivered as Level-1C. According to the [Sentinel-2 documentation](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/products-algorithms):

> Level-1C product provides **orthorectified** Top-Of-Atmosphere (TOA) reflectance, with sub-pixel multispectral registration. Cloud and land/water masks are included in the product.

Level-0, 1A and 1B are not directly disseminated to users but for completeness:

> Level-0 is compressed raw data. The Level-0 product contains all the information required to generate the Level-1 (and upper) product levels.
>
> Level-1A is uncompressed raw data with spectral bands coarsely coregistered and ancillary data appended.
>
> Level-1B data is radiometrically corrected radiance data. The physical geometric model is refined using available ground control points and appended to the product, but not applied.